# How to print a symbol for a code (in coding theory) in Latex

Tags: math-mode, symbols, mathtools

I am trying to generate a symbol for a code in coding theory in Latex. I tried `\mathcal{C}`, but it did not give me the expected output. Can Anyone give me some command or Latex packages I can use?

PD: This is the expected output
[image]
and I got [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What do you expect?

Comment: I don't think there is a specific symbol; people can use `C`, `\mathcal{C}`, `\mathbf{C}`, `\mathscr{C}` (needs `mathrsfs`) or whatever. Please add a pointer to or an image of what you mean.

Comment: Try [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) . There, you can draw the symbol you need, and detexify will list similar symbols and the required packages.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question with the expected output.

Comment: @CarlosA.AstudilloTrujillo: That is `\mathcal{C}`. If you don't get that output, then provide a minimal document that replicates your current behaviour, and also include what you're currently getting for `\mathcal{C}`.

Comment: @Werner I updated the question with my output. It seems that the problem is the font! Maybe, that is the problem! I am using the IEEE template.

Comment: @CarlosA.AstudilloTrujillo: When I use [this minimal `IEEEtran` document](https://pastebin.com/raw/RZ2zvPwc) I get the expected output. Can you provide code that replicates your problem? See [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)